# Help with Indicial equation - Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

Hi I am working on this problem to work out solutions up $x^4$ of $2xy''+(1+x)y'-2y=0$, I have worked out most of it but I am stuck with working out the indicia equation. I have got it into the form
$y''+ \frac{1+x}{2x}y'-\frac{2}{2x}y=0$ but i don't know what to do next.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The lowest-degree terms in $2x^2y''+x(1+x)y'+2xy=0$ are $2x^2y''+xy'$ which has characteristic equation $0=2m(m-1)+m=m(2m-1)$.

Comment: Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494482/how-to-find-indicial-equation).